# limit of measurable function is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be measure space and $f_n$ $:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable function.

Let $g(x) = f(x)$ if $\lim f_n(x)$ exists and $g(x)=0$ for remaning $x's$.

Claim : $g$ is measurable.